# Java command not found in OS X Snow Leopard — where can I get it?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, java

When I type `java -version` in terminal, I get

```
Command Not Found
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snow Leopard version of Java 6 Update 11 (Oct. 16, 2012) is available from Apple:

> [Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 11](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573)

More generally, all recent downloads can be found here:

> [Apple security updates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222)

Newer versions such as Java 7 won't install on any system below Lion (10.7.0), so you'll have to stick to the older version until either Oracle releases a working installer or Apple releases an upgrade (which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Download Java from the following link http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=69468.

Comment: Doesn't this link always change based on the version?

Comment: no this is the mac specific link :)

Comment: http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp is the full download list

Comment: The Java 7 you link to is for 10.7.2 and above and won't work on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the snow leopard tag, my bad.